# How to create multiple mount points with different playlists in icecast with mpd?

Tags: icecast, internet-radio, mpd, playstation

I have installed icecast and MPD with YMPD client on the server.

Currently It is running for single mount. I want to stream audio on different mounting like: /stream.ogg, /mp3, /audio with different playlists.

Below is my config files:

**1. mpd.conf**:

```
# An example configuration file for MPD.
# Read the user manual for documentation: http://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/
# or /usr/share/doc/mpd/user-manual.html


# Files and directories #######################################################
#
# This setting controls the top directory which MPD will search to discover the
# available audio files and add them to the daemon's online database. This 
# setting defaults to the XDG directory, otherwise the music directory will be
# be disabled and audio files will only be accepted over ipc socket (using
# file:// protocol) or streaming files over an accepted protocol.
#
music_directory     "/var/lib/mpd/music"
#
# This setting sets the MPD internal playlist directory. The purpose of this
# directory is storage for playlists created by MPD. The server will use 
# playlist files not created by the server but only if they are in the MPD
# format. This setting defaults to playlist saving being disabled.
#
playlist_directory      "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"
#
# This setting sets the location of the MPD database. This file is used to
# load the database at server start up and store the database while the 
# server is not up. This setting defaults to disabled which will allow
# MPD to accept files over ipc socket (using file:// protocol) or streaming
# files over an accepted protocol.
#
db_file         "/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache"
# 
# These settings are the locations for the daemon log files for the daemon.
# These logs are great for troubleshooting, depending on your log_level
# settings.
#
# The special value "syslog" makes MPD use the local syslog daemon. This
# setting defaults to logging to syslog, otherwise logging is disabled.
#
log_file            "/var/log/mpd/mpd.log"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which stores the process ID
# for use of mpd --kill and some init scripts. This setting is disabled by
# default and the pid file will not be stored.
#
pid_file            "/run/mpd/pid"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which contains information about
# most variables to get MPD back into the same general shape it was in before
# it was brought down. This setting is disabled by default and the server 
# state will be reset on server start up.
#
state_file          "/var/lib/mpd/state"
#
# The location of the sticker database.  This is a database which
# manages dynamic information attached to songs.
#
sticker_file                   "/var/lib/mpd/sticker.sql"
#
###############################################################################


# General music daemon options ################################################
#
# This setting specifies the user that MPD will run as. MPD should never run as
# root and you may use this setting to make MPD change its user ID after
# initialization. This setting is disabled by default and MPD is run as the
# current user.
#
#user               "mpd"
#
# This setting specifies the group that MPD will run as. If not specified
# primary group of user specified with "user" setting will be used (if set).
# This is useful if MPD needs to be a member of group such as "audio" to
# have permission to use sound card.
#
#group                          "nogroup"
#
# This setting sets the address for the daemon to listen on. Careful attention
# should be paid if this is assigned to anything other then the default, any.
# This setting can deny access to control of the daemon. Choose any if you want
# to have mpd listen on every address. Not effective if systemd socket
# activation is in use.
#
# For network
bind_to_address     "127.0.0.1"
#
# And for Unix Socket
#bind_to_address        "/run/mpd/socket"
#
# This setting is the TCP port that is desired for the daemon to get assigned
# to.
#
port                "6600"
#
# This setting controls the type of information which is logged. Available 
# setting arguments are "default", "secure" or "verbose". The "verbose" setting
# argument is recommended for troubleshooting, though can quickly stretch
# available resources on limited hardware storage.
#
#log_level          "default"
#
# If you have a problem with your MP3s ending abruptly it is recommended that 
# you set this argument to "no" to attempt to fix the problem. If this solves
# the problem, it is highly recommended to fix the MP3 files with vbrfix
# (available as vbrfix in the debian archive), at which
# point gapless MP3 playback can be enabled.
#
#gapless_mp3_playback           "yes"
#
# Setting "restore_paused" to "yes" puts MPD into pause mode instead
# of starting playback after startup.
#
#restore_paused "no"
#
# This setting enables MPD to create playlists in a format usable by other
# music players.
#
#save_absolute_paths_in_playlists   "no"
#
# This setting defines a list of tag types that will be extracted during the 
# audio file discovery process. The complete list of possible values can be
# found in the mpd.conf man page.
#metadata_to_use    "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date,composer,performer,disc"
#
# This setting enables automatic update of MPD's database when files in 
# music_directory are changed.
#
#auto_update    "yes"
#
# Limit the depth of the directories being watched, 0 means only watch
# the music directory itself.  There is no limit by default.
#
#auto_update_depth "3"
#
###############################################################################


# Symbolic link behavior ######################################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following 
# symbolic links outside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_outside_symlinks    "yes"
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following
# symbolic links inside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_inside_symlinks     "yes"
#
###############################################################################


# Zeroconf / Avahi Service Discovery ##########################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", service information will be published with
# Zeroconf / Avahi.
#
#zeroconf_enabled       "yes"
#
# The argument to this setting will be the Zeroconf / Avahi unique name for
# this MPD server on the network.
#
#zeroconf_name          "Music Player"
#
###############################################################################


# Permissions #################################################################
#
# If this setting is set, MPD will require password authorization. The password
# can setting can be specified multiple times for different password profiles.
#
#password                        "password@read,add,control,admin"
#
# This setting specifies the permissions a user has who has not yet logged in. 
#
default_permissions             "read,add,control,admin"
#
###############################################################################


# Database #######################################################################
#

#database {
#       plugin "proxy"
#       host "other.mpd.host"
#       port "6600"
#}

# Input #######################################################################
#

input {
        plugin "curl"
#       proxy "proxy.isp.com:8080"
#       proxy_user "user"
#       proxy_password "password"
}

#
###############################################################################

# Audio Output ################################################################
#
# MPD supports various audio output types, as well as playing through multiple 
# audio outputs at the same time, through multiple audio_output settings 
# blocks. Setting this block is optional, though the server will only attempt
# autodetection for one sound card.
#
# An example of an ALSA output:
#
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
#   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
#   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "default"   # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#   mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
#
# An example of an OSS output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "oss"
#   name        "My OSS Device"
#   device      "/dev/dsp"  # optional
#   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "/dev/mixer"    # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#}
#
# An example of a shout output (for streaming to Icecast):
#
audio_output {
    type        "shout"
    encoding    "mp3"           # optional
    name        "My Shout Stream"
    host        "localhost"
    port        "8000"
    bind_to_address "127.0.0.1"
    mount       "/mp3"
    password    "4getme!"
    quality     "5.0"
#   bitrate     "128"
    format      "44100:16:1"
#   protocol    "icecast2"      # optional
#   user        "USER"      # optional
    description "My Stream Description" # optional
#   url             "http://example.com"    # optional
#   genre       "jazz"          # optional
#   public      "no"            # optional
#   timeout     "2"         # optional
#   mixer_type      "software"              # optional
}
#
# An example of a recorder output:
#
#audio_output {
#       type            "recorder"
#       name            "My recorder"
#       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame
#       path            "/var/lib/mpd/recorder/mpd.ogg"
##      quality         "5.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined
#       bitrate         "128"                   # do not define if quality is defined
#       format          "44100:16:1"
#}
#
# An example of a httpd output (built-in HTTP streaming server):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "httpd"
#   name        "My HTTP Stream"
#   encoder     "vorbis"        # optional, vorbis or lame
#   port        "8000"
#   bind_to_address "0.0.0.0"               # optional, IPv4 or IPv6
#   quality     "5.0"           # do not define if bitrate is defined
#   bitrate     "128"           # do not define if quality is defined
#   format      "44100:16:1"
#   max_clients     "0"                     # optional 0=no limit
#}
#
# An example of a pulseaudio output (streaming to a remote pulseaudio server)
# Please see README.Debian if you want mpd to play through the pulseaudio
# daemon started as part of your graphical desktop session!
#
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "My Pulse Output"
#   server      "remote_server"     # optional
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional
}
#
# An example of a winmm output (Windows multimedia API).
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "winmm"
#   name        "My WinMM output"
#   device      "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)" # optional
#       or
#   device      "0"     # optional
#   mixer_type  "hardware"  # optional
#}
#
# An example of an openal output.
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "openal"
#   name        "My OpenAL output"
#   device      "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)" # optional
#}
#
## Example "pipe" output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "pipe"
#   name        "my pipe"
#   command     "aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or if you're want to use AudioCompress
#   command     "AudioCompress -m | aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or to send raw PCM stream through PCM:
#   command     "nc example.org 8765"
#   format      "44100:16:2"
#}
#
## An example of a null output (for no audio output):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "null"
#   name        "My Null Output"
#   mixer_type      "none"                  # optional
#}
#
# If MPD has been compiled with libsamplerate support, this setting specifies 
# the sample rate converter to use.  Possible values can be found in the 
# mpd.conf man page or the libsamplerate documentation. By default, this is
# setting is disabled.
#
#samplerate_converter       "Fastest Sinc Interpolator"
#
###############################################################################


# Normalization automatic volume adjustments ##################################
#
# This setting specifies the type of ReplayGain to use. This setting can have
# the argument "off", "album", "track" or "auto". "auto" is a special mode that
# chooses between "track" and "album" depending on the current state of
# random playback. If random playback is enabled then "track" mode is used.
# See <http://www.replaygain.org> for more details about ReplayGain.
# This setting is off by default.
#
#replaygain         "album"
#
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that have ReplayGain tags. By
# default this setting is disabled.
#
#replaygain_preamp      "0"
#
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that do NOT have ReplayGain tags.
# By default this setting is disabled.
#
#replaygain_missing_preamp  "0"
#
# This setting enables or disables ReplayGain limiting.
# MPD calculates actual amplification based on the ReplayGain tags
# and replaygain_preamp / replaygain_missing_preamp setting.
# If replaygain_limit is enabled MPD will never amplify audio signal
# above its original level. If replaygain_limit is disabled such amplification
# might occur. By default this setting is enabled.
#
#replaygain_limit       "yes"
#
# This setting enables on-the-fly normalization volume adjustment. This will
# result in the volume of all playing audio to be adjusted so the output has 
# equal "loudness". This setting is disabled by default.
#
#volume_normalization       "no"
#
###############################################################################


# Character Encoding ##########################################################
#
# If file or directory names do not display correctly for your locale then you 
# may need to modify this setting.
#
filesystem_charset      "UTF-8"
#
# This setting controls the encoding that ID3v1 tags should be converted from.
#
id3v1_encoding          "UTF-8"
#
###############################################################################


# SIDPlay decoder #############################################################
#
# songlength_database:
#  Location of your songlengths file, as distributed with the HVSC.
#  The sidplay plugin checks this for matching MD5 fingerprints.
#  See http://www.c64.org/HVSC/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.faq
#
# default_songlength:
#  This is the default playing time in seconds for songs not in the
#  songlength database, or in case you're not using a database.
#  A value of 0 means play indefinitely.
#
# filter:
#  Turns the SID filter emulation on or off.
#
#decoder {
#       plugin                  "sidplay"
#       songlength_database     "/media/C64Music/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.txt"
#       default_songlength      "120"
#       filter "true"
#}
#
###############################################################################
```

**2. icecast.xml**

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>

    <!-- IMPORTANT!
         Especially for inexperienced users:
         Start out by ONLY changing all passwords and restarting Icecast.
         For detailed setup instructions please refer to the documentation.
         It's also available here: http://icecast.org/docs/
    -->

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>4getme!</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>4getme!</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>4getme!</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->

    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>/var/lib/mpd/music</yp-url>
    </directory>
    -->
    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
         It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
         listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
    -->
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8005</port>
    <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
        <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount>  
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8006</port>
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8007</port>
        <shoutcast-mount>/live.mp3</shoutcast-mount>
    </listen-socket>

    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
    -->


    <!-- Global header settings 
         Headers defined here will be returned for every HTTP request to Icecast.

         The ACAO header makes Icecast public content/API by default
         This will make streams easier embeddable (some HTML5 functionality needs it).
         Also it allows direct access to e.g. /status-json.xsl from other sites.
         If you don't want this, comment out the following line or read up on CORS. 
    -->
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </http-headers>


    <!-- Relaying
         You don't need this if you only have one server.
         Please refer to the config for a detailed explanation.
    -->
    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8080</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->


    <!-- Mountpoints
         Only define <mount> sections if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    -->

    <!-- Default settings for all mounts that don't have a specific <mount type="normal">.
    -->
    <!-- 
    <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/server-wide-intro.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!-- Normal mounts -->

    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/stream.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>admin</username>
        <password>4getme!</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <public>1</public>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webplayer.example.org" />
                <header name="baz" value="quux" />
        </http-headers>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>


    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="headers"         value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
            <option name="header_prefix"   value="ClientHeader."/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>
    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile>

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
        -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
        -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
        <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
             Both should be PEM encoded.
        <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
        -->
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <!-- <changeowner>
            <user>icecast2</user>
            <group>icecast</group>
        </changeowner> -->
    </security>
</icecast>
```

how can I mount with different streaming file or different playlists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done multiple mounting on the icecast. For this I have create multiple instances of mpd on the server.

And start each mpd separated on different ports. Port added in configuration file.
For example:

```
mpd /etc/mpd.conf    # mpd's configuration file path for start mpd
```

After that I have started new YMPD instance on new port as mpd's client.

For example:

```
./ympd --port 6600 --webport 8085  # 6600 is mpd's port and 8085 is ympd's port.
```

Now each mpd have different playlist and different mount url for streaming audio.

Answer (score 0):

## Default Config

In the default config you have a few lines that look like this:

```xml
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
        <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount>
    </listen-socket>
```

You'll also see some commented out lines like this:

```xml
    <!-- Normal mounts -->
    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>
        ... 
    </mount>
    -->
```

## Multiple Mounts

If you have multiple source clients, you can publish to multiple streams by adding "normal" (non-default) mounts:

```xml
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
        <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount>
    </listen-socket>

    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/stream-128k</mount-name>
    </mount>
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/stream-64k</mount-name>
    </mount>
```

I believe that strict shoutcast only supports a single mount per each bound port - it has no "paths".

However, you can have as many icecast mounts as you want, provided that you have source clients to publish to them.

`liquidsoap` can make it easy to publish multiple bitrates at once.